# How do I add a table limited to only one row in mysql/django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, django-admin

I'm using Django for a small project and I want to make a table with one row to add the description of the project in it. I only need one row and nothing more since it's one description for the whole site and I don't want the user to be able to add more than one description.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something similar to the [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/sites/)?

Comment: @JamieBull no It's not! I was asking a question a lot couldn't answer it! stop down voting me!!!

Comment: I've changed the title to reflect the question. That's probably why you were getting down-votes.

Comment: thank you but I already solved the problem @JamieBull

Comment: So now people with the same problem will be more likely to find the answer (and give you upvotes in the process).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following code

```
Class Aboutus(models.Model):
    ....

    def save(self):
        # count will have all of the objects from the Aboutus model
        count = Aboutus.objects.all().count()
        # this will check if the variable exist so we can update the existing ones
        save_permission = Aboutus.has_add_permission(self)

        # if there's more than two objects it will not save them in the database
        if count < 2:
            super(Aboutus, self).save()
        elif save_permission:
            super(Aboutus, self).save()

    def has_add_permission(self):
        return Aboutus.objects.filter(id=self.id).exists()
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes this can be done.
Lets say your model is MyDescModel.

```
class MyDescModel(models.Model):
    desc = models.CharField('description', max_length=100)

def has_add_permission(self):
    return not MyDescModel.objects.exists()
```

Now you can call this

```
MyDescModel.has_add_permission()
```

before calling

```
MyDescModel.save()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Overriding has_add_permission is actual only for models inherited form ModelAdmin, but in this case only Model is used

Answer (score 0):

### Mar, 2022 Update:

The easiest and best way is using **"has_add_permission()"**:

**"models.py"**:

```py
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**"admin.py"**:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_add_permission(self, request): # Here
        return not MyModel.objects.exists()
```

You can check the documentation about [has_add_permission()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_add_permission).